# What can do I do to correct Error in missing object (R 3.0.3; performing Cokriging)?

Tags: r

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(gstat)
library(sp)

data <- read.table("meuse.txt", sep="", header=TRUE) # read txt file

# transform the data frame into a spatial data frame
coordinates(data) <- ~ x + y

## Set the coordinate system
proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

## the epsg numbers can be found here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/

# import the border shp file
border <- readOGR("meuse_area.shp", "meuse_area")
proj4string(border) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# import a raster from a ArcInfo ASCII format
zinc <- read.asciigrid("zinc.asc")
proj4string(zinc) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# Let's first create a prediction grid for the interpolation, starting from 
# the shape file
vals <- border@bbox
deltaLong <- as.integer((vals[1, 2] - vals[1, 1]) + 1.5)
deltaLat <- as.integer((vals[2, 2] - vals[2, 1]) + 1.5)
gridRes <- 0.5   # change this value to change the grid size (in metres)
gridSizeX <- deltaLong / gridRes
gridSizeY <- deltaLat / gridRes
grd <- GridTopology(vals[, 1], c(gridRes, gridRes), c(gridSizeX, gridSizeY))
pts <- SpatialPoints(coordinates(grd))
pts1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(as.data.frame(pts), 
                               data=as.data.frame(rep(1, nrow(as.data.frame(pts)))))

Overlay <- overlay(pts1, border)
pts1$border <- Overlay
nona <- na.exclude(as.data.frame(pts1))
coordinates(nona) <- ~ x + y
gridded(nona) <- TRUE
proj4string(nona) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")  # remember to set the coordinate 
                                             # system also for the prediction grid
writeAsciiGrid(nona, "prediction_grid.asc")


# For the Co-kriging we need to obtain the value of the covariate for each 
# observation
over <- overlay(zinc, data)
data$zinc <- over$zinc.asc
str(as.data.frame(data))

# also the prediction grid need to be overlayed with the covariate
over <- overlay(zinc, nona)
nona$zinc <- over$zinc.asc

# for the cokriging, the first thing to do is create an object with the
# function gstat() that contains both the variable and the covariate
str(data)
complete.cases("data")
str(zinc)
complete.cases("zinc")
g <- gstat(id="lead", formula=lead ~ 1, data=data)
g <- gstat(g, id="zinc", formula=zinc ~ 1, data=data)


# Fitting the variogram
# first, plot the residual variogram
vario <- variogram(g)
```

> Error in na.fail.default(list(zinc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
>   :    missing values in object

I know that there is no missing in zinc when I edit the object in Notepad. What did I miss? There is no NA in zinc.asc.[These are my data.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xqtiu1595bzjhk/NEW%20EXPERIMENT.rar?dl=0)

I want to perform cokriging and I am stuck with variogram.

Comment: Could not run Line 37 `raster::overlay(pts1, border)` .

Comment: Can you suggest any other way? For me, it's running fine.

Comment: Don't know, I just run your code and got an error in this line. Perhaps unload all packages first to reproduce.

Comment: Was it really an error or just a warning message for deprecated function? I just ignored the warning message since it was not an error.

Comment: `Overlay <- overlay(pts1, border)` yields **Error in overlay(pts1, border) : could not find function "overlay"**, and `Overlay <- raster::overlay(pts1, border)` yields **Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"SpatialPointsDataFrame", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"’**

Comment: now, that's interesting because I do not have the error when I run the code.

Comment: EDIT: When I updated my R to the latest version, 3.4.3, I got the same error. I was using R 3.0.3.

Any takers on why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also you can change the two lines :

```
overlay=overlay(pts1,border)
pts1$border=Overlay
```

by

```
pts1$border=over(pts1,border)
```

Answer (score 0):

One cause of the confusion here may be that sp used to include it's own overlay function.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/0.9-7/topics/overlay

However the most recent version of the sp package replaced the "overlay" function with "over". I do no believe raster::overlay behaves the same as the overlay function from sp 0.9-7